# Tool to find usage of classes in jars in the whole project

Tags: java, jar, eclipse-plugin, classpath, dependency-management

I am looking for a tool that can tell me how and where all jars (in the classpath)and their classes are being used/referenced in the whole project. Do we have any tool/eclipse plug-in or a nice method to do that.

Comment: Eclipse can do it, with standard find usage ... References->Workspace

Comment: Yeah, But I have a many jars in classpath that I need to find their references in the code.

Comment: Then press link with editor button at the top-left corner

Comment: Anton. Please elaborate.

Comment: I had the same issue withe eclipse. I found a work around for my issue. What I did was , I added the projects ( I had the source code with me) which are available to the other classes via jars, in the working set and I searched the usage in that 'working set'

Answer (score 1):

Try [dependency-analyzer](http://www.dependency-analyzer.org/), this is a quote from the documentation:

> it is capable of finding the dependencies of
>
> a single class all classes in one package all classes in one container
>   (i.e. Java Archive or file directory)